# The probability that a white ball will be drawn before a black ball

Tags: probability

The following question is taken from Sveshnikov, A. A.. Problems in Probability Theory, Mathematical Statistics and Theory of Random Functions (Dover Books on Mathematics):

> An urn contains $n$ white balls, $m$ black balls and $l$ red balls, which are drawn at random one at a time (a) without replacement, (b) with replacement of each ball to the urn after each draw. Find the probability that in both cases a white ball will be drawn before a black one.

The author explains the solution the following way:

> SOLUTION. Let $P_I$ be the probability for a white ball to be drawn before a black one, and $P_{II}$ be the probability for a black white ball to be drawn before a white ball. The probability $P_I$ is the sum of probabilities of drawing a white ball immediately after a red ball, two red balls, and so forth. Thus, in the case without replacement we have

> $P_I=\frac{n}{n+m+l}+\frac{ln}{(n+m+l)(n+m+l-1)}+\frac{l(l-1)n}{(n+m+l)(n+m+l-1)(n+m+l-2)}+...$

> and in the case with replacement,

> $P_I=\frac{n}{n+m+l}+\frac{ln}{(n+m+l)^2}+\frac{l^2n}
> {(n+m+l)^3}+...=\frac{n}{n+m}$.

> To obtain the probabilities $P_{II}$, replace $n$ by $m$ and $m$ by $n$ in the preceding formulas. From this it follows in both cases that $P_I:P_{II} = n:m$. Furthermore, since $P_I + P_{II} = 1$, the required probability in the case without replacement is also $P_I = n/(n+m)$

The case with the replacement is easy and the formula can be summarized as $n/(n+m)$ because of the geometric series. I just have problem following the argument for the case without replacement that just because the probabilities are symmetric and they add up to 1, do they always have to n/(n+m) for the while balls and m/(n+m) for the black balls? (in case of without replacement).

In other words how if $_:_{}=:$ and if $_+_{}=1$ leads to $P_I=n/(n+m)$?

Thanks,

Comment: Replacement (or not) has nothing to do with it.  The red balls don't matter...there are $n+m$ "relevant" balls.  Eventually you will get a relevant ball, and the probability that that ball is white is $\frac n{n+m}$.

Comment: Yes. Consider drawing a red ball as doing nothing. Then the problem becomes: draw a ball from $n$ white balls and $m$ black balls, what is the probability of drawing a white ball?

Comment: If $P_I:P_{II} = n:m$ and if $P_I + P_{II} = 1$, then it follows necessarily that $P_I = n/(n+m)$. It doesn't matter whether $P_I$ and $P_{II}$ are probabilities or lengths of line segments or the prices of two kinds of tea or just two numbers with no other interpretation. Is that the fact you want someone to show you, or do you have some question about why $P_I:P_{II} = n:m$ or why $P_I + P_{II} = 1$?

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I did not follow how if $_:_{}=:$
 and if $_+_{}=1$ leads to $P_I=n/(n+m)$

Comment: Okay, I got it now, basically both of the formulas of $P_I$ are in form of $n*a$. $P_{II}$ will be is also in form of $m*a$ and their sum is 1. This makes $a=1/(n+m)$. Therefore the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases there are $n+m$ *equiprobable* candidates for becoming the first not-red drawn ball.

That means that each of these candidates has probability $\frac1{n+m}$ to become that ball.

Summing up the probabilities of all $n$ white balls we find $\frac{n}{n+m}$ for the probability that the first not-red drawn ball will be a white ball.